# Set Drawer width to the width of the largest child

Tags: flutter, layout, drawer

Is it possible to set the width of a drawer in Flutter to the width of its widetst child to avoid f. e. clipping of the DrawerHeader?

That is what it should look like:
green is the screen, grey the drawer

[image]

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Example was added

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                  child: Text('User name'),
                ),
              ),
              Text('Text'),
              Text(
                'Long loong looooooong very very very long text',
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]